# Selecting a value from an n:n relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

I currently have three tables: `users`, `roles`, and a `user_to_role` “pivot” table defining a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `roles`:

**`users`**

```php
protected $fillable = [
   'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

**`user_to_role`**

```php
protected $fillable = [
   'id', 'user_id', 'role_id'
];
```

**`roles`**

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'role_name', 
];
```

The `role_name` values are `admin` and `client`.

When a user logs in, I want to show a view for the specific role that the user is assigned. I don't really know how to do that in the controller, however. I have something like the following, but I know it won’t work:

```php
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->role_id==1) {
        // and something here which I don't know
        return view('homeadmin');
    }
}
```

I know I have to take the `id` from the `roles` table, make the connection with the `user_to_role` pivot, and then join that with the `users` table, but I don't really know how.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a relationship between `User` model and `Role` model.

```php
# User.php

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_to_role');
}
```

Optionally, define the relationship on `Role` model as well.

```php
# Role.php

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_to_role');
}
```

Then, you can access the relationship and use collection methods on it.

```php
public function index()
{
    // or Auth::user()->roles->contains('role_name', 'admin') if you want to be specific
    if (Auth::user()->roles->contains('id', 1)) {
        return view('homeadmin');
    }

    return view('homeuser');
}
```

---

Optionally, you could make a method in the `User` model to check if an user is `admin` or `client`.

```php
# User.php

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->roles->contains('id', 1); // or contains('role_name', 'admin')
}

public function isClient()
{
    return $this->roles->contains('id', 2); // or contains('role_name', 'client')
}
```

```php
public function index()
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return view('homeadmin');
    }

    return view('homeclient');
}
```

---

- [Eloquent Relationships - Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- [Collections - `contains()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have `User` and `Role` Model mapping to your `users` and `roles` table, the convention is to name your pivot table `role_user`. But you can get along with your current table naming as well.

I would agree the answer of [IGP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68183090/11898471) and add a few more suggestions.

If you just need to implement role and user and don't have to build it yourself, there are plenty of existing packages that can help you handle role-permission. You don't really needs to build from scratch. For example, depends on the Laravel version you use, you may choose;

1. [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)
2. [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer)
3. [Zizaco/Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust)

If you would like to implement role management yourself, when you define your relationship, you need to think about if a user would have multiple roles in the future. Based on what you show us right now, there are only `client` and `admin` role. Looks like a user would only be either client or admin but not both.  And if you are sure those are the only two roles and a user would be either one, you don't need to have `roles` table at all. You can just add a boolean column such as `is_admin` in `users` table to flag the role.

But let's say you will have more roles, and a user can have multiple roles at the same time. Then you DO need to define a many to many relationship. Other answers already provide example on that pretty well. I would also suggest to define a universal role-handling model function to check all roles. In your `User.php` model,

```php
public function hasRole($role)
{
    // check if user have any of the specified roles
    if (is_array($role)) {
        foreach($role as $r) {
           if ($this->roles->contains('role_name', $r)) {
              return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return $this->roles->contains('role_name', $role);
    }
}
```

That way, in anywhere in your App, you can check your user role by calling

```php
Auth::user()->hasRole('admin');
```

or check if user contains any role in a list by calling

```php
Auth::user()->hasRole(['admin', 'client']);
```